# Would it be possible to a add marijuana to this site’s parameters as being on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, tags, asking-questions, site-evaluation

**Beer, Wine, Spirits & Marijuana**

Would it be possible to a add marijuana to this site’s parameters as being on topic?

**Marijuana** is slowly becoming permitted as a legal recreation drug, just like the consumption of alcohol!

I do not believe there would be as yet a community support strong enough for marijuana on it’s own and the present site has little traffic. Thus I am wondering if we could add marijuana to the list of things as being on topic here, or if it would be even considered appropriate to do so?

> [**Responsible use of Recreational Drugs**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recreational_drug_use)
>
> The concept of "responsible drug use" is that a person can use drugs recreationally or otherwise with reduced or eliminated risk of negatively affecting other aspects of one's life or other people's lives. Advocates of this philosophy point to the many well-known artists and intellectuals who have used drugs, experimentally or otherwise, with few detrimental effects on their lives. Responsible drug use becomes problematic only when the use of the substance significantly interferes with the user's daily life.
>
> Responsible drug use advocates that users should not take drugs at the same time as activities such as driving, swimming, operating machinery, or other activities that are unsafe without a sober state. Responsible drug use is emphasized as a primary prevention technique in harm-reduction drug policies. Harm-reduction policies were popularized in the late 1980s, although they began in the 1970s counter-culture, when cartoons explaining responsible drug use and the consequences of irresponsible drug use were distributed to users. Another issue is that the illegality of drugs in itself also causes social and economic consequences for those using them—the drugs may be "cut" with adulterants and the purity varies wildly, making overdoses more likely—and legalization of drug production and distribution would reduce these and other dangers of illegal drug use. Harm reduction seeks to minimize the harm that can occur through the use of various drugs, whether legal (e.g., **alcohol and nicotine**), or illegal (e.g., heroin and cocaine). For example, people who take drugs intravenously (cocaine, heroin) can minimize harm to both themselves and members of the community through proper injecting technique, using new needles and syringes each time, and proper disposal of all injecting equipment.
>
> **Common recreational drugs**
>
> - [Alcohol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol): Most drinking alcohol is ethanol, CH3CH2OH. Drinking alcohol creates intoxication, relaxation and lowered inhibitions. It is produced by the fermentation of sugars by yeasts to create wine, beer, and distilled liquor (e.g., vodka, rum, gin, etc.). In most areas of the world, it is legal for those over a certain age (18 in most countries). It is an IARC Group 1 carcinogen and a teratogen. Alcohol withdrawal can be life-threatening.
> - [Cannabis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabis_(drug)): Its common forms include marijuana and hashish, which are smoked or eaten. It contains at least 85 cannabinoids. The primary psychoactive component is THC, which mimics the neurotransmitter anandamide, named after the Hindu *ananda*, "joy, bliss, delight".

Although I am only postulating adding **marijuana** to be added to the subjects as being on topic here. One could add other recreational drugs that are considered legal as a recreational drug use (in certain regions), but that seems doubtful at the present moment in time.

Comment: Do not care about votes, as I am simply offering a suggestion for the site. That is why I brought it up as a discussion topic, to see what the desire of the community would be.

Answer (score 2):

I would be against bringing cannabis into scope, for the following reasons:

While I support scope changes over time, I don't feel that marijuana fits here - it is not brewed or distilled. It is not a drink. The audience for questions covering the preparation of alcoholic drinks is really not the same as that for marijuana growth/preparation/usage. Also, while in the US it may be getting legalised in many states, that is an outlier country, not really representative of the world.

I **would** however support a merging of Homebrewing and Beer, Wine and Spirits, as they are very closely related sites, with a significant crossover in population and attention.

Regarding [user1271772's suggestion](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/a/271/5064) of Coffee - there I do not think we have the same sort of overlap. Coffee is a very different type of drink, with its own lore, preparation and adherents.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is why I want the discussion.

Comment: In the scope of brewing alcoholic beverages, beer, wine, spirits... I would suggest any subsequent ingredient should not be excluded from the discussion.  At the same time, being responsible with safety is a huge factor that also should not be neglected when dealing with any ingredient that could have a potentially dangerous effect.  All "recreational" "drugs" are potentially left out because of their dangers?  When in reality Alcohol can be just as dangerous.  
Maybe I'm misreading the post /or rules, but are we not allowed to talk about Marijuana in scope of brewing as an ingredient?

Comment: @mrSidX - I think you have got the wrong end of the stick here. This is not about disallowing ingredients at all. Please re-read Ken's question to see what is being proposed.

Comment: I was led here via link from another post that was based around the topic of brewing with Marijuana.  I soon realized this thread wasn't what it at first seemed, despite me adding my 2 cents in my comment above.  Thanks for clarifying, but I'm still curious why any ingredient used in any brewing craft process would remain or should remain off topic, when the topic clearly revolves around use of that ingredient... ie.. Sugar free VS Sugar based XYZ...
Would discussing Sugar in relation be off topic too?  Or Just a particular substance / ingredient like say, Marijuana?  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @mrSidX I think you are still misunderstanding the question. Currently this site is about Beer, Wine and Spirits. It is not about Coffee, or Marijuana, or Herbs, or Grapes (although we have questions about alcohol that contains those things). But should this be Coffee, Beer, Wine and Sprits? Or Beer, Wine, Spirits and Marijuana? No.

Comment: Are crafting topics on this site off limits or out of scope?  and if no, are recipes, ingredients that aid towards the end goals out of scope?
I understand there is a homebrew stack, where such topics with focus on ingredients and process may be more appropriate? 
Thanks for your patience with myself being a newcomer to this stack, and my potential lack of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely inactive site, with 0.2 questions/day, which is 50x smaller than the 10 questions/day which was once quoted as the requirement for graduating from Beta.

I [recently posted](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/q/486/18390) on the Meta site of Homebrewing Stack Exchnage, a question asking the community why they were so inactive, and got some valuable insight from the answers, but even they are averaging 2x as many questions/day as this site right now.

#### Therefore I support your suggestion to expand the scope.

In fact why stop at marijuana? The coffee stack exchange has only 0.1 questions/day, and people will be interested in other recreational drugs too.

I propose: **CAS Stack Exchange** where CAS stands for Chemically Active Substances. We combine coffee, beer, wine, spirits, marijuana, homebrewing, and other topics, perhaps even pharmaceuticals --- I was a bit disappointed when the recent pharmaceuticals Area51 proposal didn't get approved, since I often have questions about some of the chemically active prescriptions I've been recommended from my doctor. I'm sure also anyone who's been prescribed anti-psychotics, anti-depressants, mood stabilizers, or anxiety mitigated drugs like lorazopam, will attest to the fact that discussing those is not much different from discussing beer, wine, spirits, and marijuana, as they have very similar affects on the body.

Comment: I believe a **CAS** title would be misleading, and have a negative affect on the community here. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @KenGraham I was worried about that. Do you think coffee and homebrewing should be included too though? There seems to be at least 3 somewhat related sites (Beer/Wine/Spirits + Homebrewing + Coffee) which are all standing at fewer than 0.5 questions/day, each).

Comment: I would be okay with Homebrewing, but not coffee. At least at this moment in time.

Comment: Why marijuana but not coffee? How about "alcohol, canibis and caffeine" instead of "beer wine and spirits"?

Comment: Coffee SE has a better following at the present moment.  Homebrewing is like us is floundering somewhat.